# Print the characters inside most child parenthesis and print that parenthesis count

Tags: php

I have a string `$string = "(a(b,c)((d,e))(f,g))";`

I want to print the characters inside most child parenthesis and print that parenthesis count

**Output should be**

```
> Most child parenthesis: 3
> Value contains: d,e
```

Comment: Step through the string one character at a time, if the character is `(`, increase a counter, if it's `)`, decrease the counter; if you've hit the highest counter number so far, save every following character in a separate variable as the searched-for values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my quick implementation:

```
$string = "(a(b,c)((d,e))(f,g))";

$count = 0;
$max_count = 0;

$final_string = '';
for ( $i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++ )
{
    if ( $string[$i] == '(' )
    {
        $count++;
        if ( $count > $max_count )
        {
            $max_count = $count;
            $final_string = "";
        }
    }
    else if ( $string[$i] == ')' )
    {
        $count--;
    }
    else if ( $count == $max_count )
    {
        $final_string .= $string[$i];
    }

}

echo "Most child parenthesis: ", $max_count, "\nValue contains: ", $final_string;
```

You can see it in action [here](http://www.tehplayground.com/#nD91asE2y).